# mod_rewrite proxy returns ip address instead of hostname

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got the following setup:

```
<Proxy balancer://clusterX>
  BalancerMember http://app.server:1234 
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://clusterY>
  BalancerMember http://app.server.2:1234
</Proxy>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 1$|2$|3$|4$|0$
RewriteRule ^/something-here(.*)$ balancer://clusterX/something-here$1 [P,L]
```

In this case when a request comes to something here from an ip address edning on 1,2,3 or 4 mod_rewrite sends it to clusterX. However, if I change something in the request via my browser, it sends me directly to appp.server:1234 (in my case this is ip address) and not on the original hostname where I'm accessing both clusers.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself.

Basically, mod_rewrite forwards the request to the app server, but when the app server data back, there's no module to handle the rewriting of the url in the HTTP header.

In order to make this work add this:

ProxyPassReverse /something-here balancer://clusterX/something-here